# Unclear formula for LED resistor calculation

Tags: led, resistors

On this page:
[LED Series Resistor Calculator and Formula](http://www.newark.com/led-series-resistor-calculator?CMP=KNC-BUSA-GEN-KWL&mckv=%7Cpcrid%7C%7Bcreative%7D%7C)

Vs, Vf and If can be filled in and the resistor is calculated.
The formula is even added: R = ((Vs - Vf) / If)

However, when e.g. filling in 5 Vs, 2 Vf, 0.02 If, Resistor is 125

While if I calculate it manually

```
R = ((5 - 2) / 0.02) = 150
```

To make it more unclear, when Vs == Vf, it is advised still to use a resistor and it gives a value (which it does), while the formula should give 0 ohm. So I have the idea the resistor value is calculated 'better', but the formula notation is wrong. But what is correct?

Comment: In real life LEDs, Vf is not a single voltage, it's a range. The calculator probably has some built in safety fudge factor.

Comment: Try a few more values and see if you can reverse engineer their formula!

Comment: It appears they are calculating \$R=\frac{V_s}{V_f\cdot I_f}\$, which isn't even dimensionally correct.

Comment: @jonk Thanks (and others too) ... in another website (http://ledcalculator.net/) I get with values V 5, Vf 2, 20mA, 150 ohm, and with Vf == V (e.g. 5V) 1 ohm, so there is some less or more safety depending on the formula used.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers Yes. Their formula is screwed up, probably because the stupid web site programmer didn't have a shred of a clue about anything and couldn't read the specification paper they were handed with intelligence. Just a monkey who saw "-" and read "/" for some reason that day. No one checked up on it, either.

Comment: @MichaelKeijzers: I have my own attempt at an LED [Loadline graphing tool](http://lednique.com/iv-curves/loadline-resistance-graphic-tool/). See if that helps in any way. The curves are a bit off. I'm still working on it.

Comment: @Transistor What would make it really useful is if I could enter a datasheet HTTP link, it would read the datasheet for me pulling out the appropriate parameters and information, then plot the curve and the indicated load line plus intercept point. Oh. With error bands for part variation, binning, temperature variation, and long term drift, too.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers The written formula is correct, but the calculator is bugged. You can write an e-mail to element14 to fix it.

Comment: Thanks all ... actually I'm currently not involved with leds, but I just answered another question and thought to 'check' my thoughts against a website (which is wrong seems to be).

Comment: Here's the calculation code snippet that I grabbed from the website: `click(
 function(v)
 {
  v.preventDefault();
  var 
   e=m("#Vs").val(),
   t=m("#Vf").val(),
   a=m("#If").val(),
   l=m("#R").val();
   ""==e ? m("#Vs").val(l*t*a) : ""==t ? m("#Vf").val(e/a/l) : ""==a ? m("#If").val(e/t/l) : m("#R").val(e/t/a)
 }
)` Looks like quite interesting and wrong.

Comment: I sent a message to them to fix it :-)

Comment: @RohatKılıç Eew, that looks like it was coded by a 5 year old. That's nasty.